# Pass *this as argument to method invoked by thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a member function which I cannot unit test easily (it listens to sockets etc):

```
void MyClass::func()
{
    listen();
    send();
}
```

So I want to template it and then I can pass a mock object in my test:

```
template<class OBJECT>
void func(OBJECT& obj)
{
    obj.listen();
    obj.send();
}
```

and then I'd do:

```
func(*this);
```

The above compiles when I do a normal function call. However, when I spawn a thread and call it:

```
std::thread t1(&MyClass::func, this, *this);
```

I get compiler errors (see below) referring to decltype. Is there a way I can still achieve this?

```
/opt/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/thread:127:8: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (MyClass::*)(MyClass &),
      MyClass *, MyClass> >' requested here
              __make_invoker(std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
```

However, the following works:

```
void MyClass::x()
{
    func(*this);
}

std::thread t1(&MyClass::x, this);
```

Comment: Are both `func` and `x` members of the class?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov yes

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov edited to make this clearer

Comment: What is the type of `this` in this code `std::thread t1(&MyClass::func, this, *this);`?

Comment: It's quite a complex class. It does not have a move operator, or copy constructor, just a default constructor and destructor. Is there a particular function I need to implement to pass it to std::thread?

Comment: @Eljay but I can when it's std::thread t1(&MyClass::x, this);?

Comment: @Eljay but it's not static. See the code above. std::thread t1(&MyClass::x, this); works with void MyClass::x();

Comment: `std::thread` supports the pattern you are using.  I learned something new.  Thank you, and sorry for my confusion.  (I've deleted my incorrect commentary.)

Comment: @Eljay no worries. Gave you rep for apologising!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issue in your code:

First, you cannot pass function templates to the std::thread constructor. You must explicitly specify what specialisation of the function template to use, which in this case, would be `&MyClass::func<MyClass>`.

Second you are trying to pass a reference as an argument to the constructor of `std::thread`. When the `std::thread` constructor is called, the first argument is the function to run concurrently, and the others are the argument to the function. The other arguments are *moved* and then passed as argument to the function. This is fine if the argument is a pointer or a variable, but causes an issue if the function expects a non-const lvalue as an argument.

You can solve both issues by constructing `std::thread` with lambdas:

```
std::thread t1([=]{
    this->func(*this);
});
```

Conversely, you could use std::ref, a reference wrapper, in the std::thread constructor, and explicitly specify the function template specialisation:

```
#include<functional>

std::thread t1(&MyClass::func<MyClass>, this, std::ref(*this));
```

Personally, I much prefer constructing `std::threads` with lambdas, as it is cleaner and less error prone.