# Calling a member function in a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

This is a class:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class A {
  private:
    void render(int, std::vector<std::vector<int>>&) {
        //do stuff
    };

    void renderSegment() {
        int var1 = 1;
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> var2;

        std::thread t(????);
        t.join();
    };
};
```

Here are some attempts:

```
std::thread t([this, var1, &var2] {renderSegment(var1, var2);});
std::thread t(renderSegment, var1, std::ref(var2));
std::thread t(&A::renderSegment, var1, std::ref(var2));
std::thread t(&renderSegment, this, var1, std::ref(var2));
```

I want to call `render(var1, var2)` in the function `renderSegment()`. I've look at a couple of questons, like this

[Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

and this

[C++11 multithreading with class member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754438/c11-multithreading-with-class-member-function)

but nothing seems to work. Even when it looks like it should work, the compiler tells me that that I'm attempting to reference a deleted function `std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)`.

I'm using C++17 and MVSC, for better or for worse. I haven't enabled any kind of special flags, but I was unable to find any that would explicitly enable multithreading in the program itself (there is one for multithreaded compilation).

How do I make it work?

EDIT: Here is longer, but real code:

Renderer.h

```
#include <glm/vec2.hpp>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>

#include <complex>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class State;

class Renderer {
public:
    void renderScene();
    Renderer(State& state);

private:
    State& m_state;

    void renderMandelbrot(int power);
    double mandelbrot(std::complex<double> c, int power);
    void renderSegment(
        int segmentStart,
        int segmentSize,
        int power,
        std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>>& colours);
};
```

Renderer.cpp

```
#include "Renderer.h"

#include "State.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>

void Renderer::renderScene() {
    renderMandelbrot(m_state.m_power);
}

Renderer::Renderer(State& state) :
    m_state(state) {

    std::srand(time(NULL));
    m_state.m_threadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
}

void Renderer::renderMandelbrot(int power) {
    std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>> colours;
    colours.resize(m_state.m_height);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_state.m_height; ++i) {
        colours[i].resize(m_state.m_width);
    }

    int segmentSize = m_state.m_height / m_state.m_threadCount;
    int segmentStart = 0;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int k = 0; k < m_state.m_threadCount - 1; ++k, segmentStart += segmentSize) {
        std::thread t = std::thread(&Renderer::renderMandelbrot, this,
            segmentStart,
            segmentStart + segmentSize,
            power,
            std::ref(colours));
        threads.push_back(t);
    }
    std::thread t = std::thread(&Renderer::renderMandelbrot, this,
            segmentStart,
            m_state.m_height,
            power,
            std::ref(colours));
        threads.push_back(t);

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

void Renderer::renderSegment(
    int segmentStart,
    int segmentEnd,
    int power,
    std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec3>>& colours) {

    for (int j = segmentStart; j < segmentEnd; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_state.m_width; ++i) {
            colours[j][i] = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

State is pretty much just a bunch of values, so I omitted the code for it.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 I've actually answered a question like this. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377194/13375552

Comment: Well I must be missing something, but I don't know why. If you can give me an example that should work with this particular case, it will either work and I'll feel extremely stupid, or I'll get an error that might tell us more about what's going on.

Comment: @AzamBham Your answer works great until I have to pass the reference, then it tells me 'qualifiers dropped in binding reference' and I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tried what you wrote, but it still complains about attempting to reference a deleted function I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 I think you tried `std::thread t(&A::render, *this, var1, std::ref(var2));` instead of `std::thread t(&A::render, this, var1, std::ref(var2));`.

Comment: If the linked question does not solve your problem, then the problem is caused by something not included in the question. The linked question is a duplicate of this question as it was asked. Consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: I tried both, both giving me the same error. I'll try to expand the example.

Comment: Can you make "void render ()" static ? If yes, it could help.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Please read this article : [MCVE]. The example is not compilable and not verifiable. You almost had it right the first time when you made a small code sample, except for the fact that it didn't actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans I could, but then Renderer as an object doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 `push_back(t)` is trying to copy your thread into the vector. Use `push_back(std::move(t))`.

Comment: That was it. It's always something stupid. Always.